# Missing semicolon before return

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

This is my piece of code, I'm compiling in VS2010:

```
static inline int ff_insert_inpad(AVFilterContext *f, unsigned index, AVFilterPad *p)  
    {  
        int ret = ff_insert_pad(index, &f->nb_inputs, offsetof(AVFilterLink, dstpad), &f->input_pads, &f->inputs, p); 

    #if FF_API_FOO_COUNT
    FF_DISABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS  
        f->input_count = f->nb_inputs;  
    FF_ENABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS        
    #endif

        return ret; // error here


    }
```

I'm getting errors like:

```
2>c:\users\awki6\desktop\ffmpeg\libavfilter\internal.h(271): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'return'
```

Comment: Well what do the macros expand to? Have you tried, you know, adding a semicolon after the macros?

Comment: I would say the error is pretty obvious: You are missing a semicolon. You better look at what the `FF_DISABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS` and `FF_ENABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS` does, if they need to have a semicolon added to them.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but does VS2010 allow whitespaces before preprocessor instructions ?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg looking at the source code of FFmpeg's [internal.h](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/libavutil_2internal_8h_source.html), these guys are just pragma directives, so no semicolon necessary. Here's probably missing a semicolon or something else in another location, and that confuses the compiler.